# How to go about instantiating templates based on symbols missing in an object file?

Tags: c++, templates, code-generation, build-process, instantiation

(This question is a bit obscure without a lot of motivation so please bear with me.)

For the sake of discussion let's assume I have two files, `a.cpp` and `b.hpp`. Suppose `a.cpp` has the declaration

```
template <typename T> void foo(T& t);
```

and somewhere in the code it has the commands:

```
foo<int>(1234);
foo<double>(12.34);
```

while `b.hpp` holds the actual (templated) definition and nothing else.

Now, `a.cpp`, compiled without including `b.hpp` will compile into an object file, `a.o`, which is expecting to be linked with other files containing the object code for `foo<int>` and `foo<double>`. In itself, `b.hpp` makes no instantiations of `foo()`, so it's useless to compile it alone.

However, if I were to determine which instantiations are necessary, and generate `a.aux.cpp` containing minimal code to instantiate exactly those templates needed for `a.cpp`, I would not have to manually ensure the instantiations are made.

So, how do I go about achieving this? I was thinking along the lines of doing

```
nm --undefined-only a.cpp | sed 's/^ *//;' | c++filt | grep foo
```

to get the signatures. Then I need to force their instantiation without actually causing any other side-effects... perhaps define a variable whose type is a pointer to `foo<T>` for each value of `T` I find.

Anyway, this all seems very kludgy and I was wondering whether some build-related tools do this for you. Or whether I should have another approach altogether.

Comment: This maybe of interest: http://kuhllib.com/2012/01/22/source-organization-of-templates/

Comment: Or http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/templates-defn-vs-decl.html

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's anything you could use out of the box. You might try to write your own "needed instantiation extractor" with tools such as [LibClang](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/Tooling.html).

Also note that the only legal way to get an instantiation usable in other translation units is to request an explicit instantiation:

```
template void foo(int& t);
```

Comment: It is the best and only way. If you don't do an explicit instantiation and don't have the definition available in every translation unit that requires an implicit instantiation, the code is ill-formed NDR ([temp]/p6).

Comment: @T.C. Thanks, updated. I guess I shouldn't really try answering at 9p.m. after a hard day...

Comment: Don't you mean, `template void foo<int>(int& t);` ?

Comment: @einpoklum The parameters can get deduced; no need to explicitly specify.